# For loop that takes turns between printing one thing or the other python

Tags: python

Not sure how else to word the title, but this is what I need:

Print either the number zero, the number one or a phrase in no consecutive order twenty times. This is what I have:

```
    n = 0
    x = “hello”
    for i in range(20):
        print(n, end= ‘’) or print(n+1, end= ‘’) or print(x)
```

The only problem is that it prints them out in order so that it is always 01hello01hello01hello and so on. I need it to be randomized so that it could print something like 000hello1hello101 or just any random variation of the three variables.

Let me know how :)

Comment: try running `print("apple") or print("banana") or print("orange")` in the interpreter and see what you get - `or` doesn't make a choice, it turns two true/false things into one true/false thing

Comment: You have the wrong types of quotes. Python (like most programming languages) uses straight quotes, not curly quotes. Turn off "smart quotes" when editing code.

Comment: When you write `if a == 1 or a == 2:`, it's not making a choice. Why would you think that it works differently with `print`?

Comment: Regarding title wording, I think "takes turns" implies non-random ordering, or interlacing of values. It would be strange to join a card game where you take turns in a random order with repeats allowed. Maybe you end up with someone who never gets a turn? Better would be something like "For loop to choose random value from allowed values"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```py
import random
choices = [1, 0, "hello"]
for i in range(20):
    print(random.choice(choices))
```

Answer (score 7):

Your question is hard to understand, but I think this will help.
If you want to randomize, then try importing `random`

```
import random
my_strings=["foo", "bar", "baz"]

for i in range(10):
    print(random.choose(my_strings))
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `random.choice`:

```
import random
choices = (0, 1, "hello")
print(''.join(str(random.choice(choices)) for _ in range(20)))
```

Answer (score 4):

The "random" module is very useful for these situations, especially the "shuffle" function.

The "suffle" function allows you to shuffle a list, this function requires the list, and optionally a function that returns a random number between 0 and 1 (by default random.random). This function does not return a list but modifies it.

```
import random

# Create 20 elements of each vars
vars_0 = ["0"] * 20
vars_1 = ["1"] * 20
vars_2 = ["hello"] * 20

# Join the elements
super_list = vars_0 + vars_1 + vars_2

# Mix the super list
random.shuffle(super_list) 

# Convert the list to a string
print("".join(super_list))
```

The result

```
hellohello001hello01hellohello1hello10hello011101hello1101hellohellohello1001hello100001hello101hello00hello0hellohellohellohello1001hello10
```

I think it is quite readable solution